# Too much music volume difference

Tags: 14.04, sound, volume-control

I've a problem that some applications have quite a low volume, but others are too high. For example Videos has a low volume (although on max), but the browser and Transmission are way too loud.

How can I fix this? Something that keeps the volume levels the same over the whole system?

Answer (score 0):

Install `pavucontrol` (available in the universe repositories) via:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

and configure the volume separately for each application. To do that, start the application and change the volume level in `pavucontrol`.

[image]

Comment: I only see Videos there, not my other applications. Everything I see is on 100%,

Comment: Have you started the other applications?

Comment: Yes, they are all running.